# How to add Swarmify Video Player plugin JS file in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-applications, angular-cli, video.js

I am developing an Angular Web App.

I am using Swarmify Web Player to play Video

But they provided a JS file that have to be inluded in Script tag like this:

```
<script data-cfasync="false">
    var swarmoptions = {
        swarmcdnkey: "f4d864ed-5671-486f-b371-1b5cb3336170",
        autoreplace: {
            youtube: false
        }
    };
</script>
<script data-cfasync="false" src="https://assets.swarmcdn.com/cross/swarmdetect.js"></script>
```

To play  a Video

```
  <smartvideo   style="min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;" src="http://www.example.com/sample.mp4" width="600" height="600" controls></smartvideo>
```

But I don't know how to add this JS type plugins

**Steps I did**

I added this script tags in index.html page of the app

After that I added the `SmartVideo tag` in Video-Page.Component.html .. , I got the following error:

```
Swarmify - swarmdetect.js: Document Write Succeeded swarmdetect.js:1:553

Error: Template parse errors:
'smartvideo' is not a known element:

1. If 'smartvideo' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. (" <div class="single-video"> [ERROR ->]<smartvideo src="https://videos.fetnation.com/file/videostream/5c4c5774450d2923589c09a6_The Dark Kn"): ng:///AppModule/VideoPageComponent.html@18:10
```

So I used a different method :

I added these lines in `videopage.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {

    let s2 = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
    s2.type = 'text/javascript';
    s2.src =  'https://assets.swarmcdn.com/cross/swarmdetect.js';
    this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, s2);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit ()
  {
    let s = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.text = ` var swarmoptions = {
      swarmcdnkey: "f4d864ed-5670-486f-b371-1b5cb3336170",
      autoreplace: {
          youtube: false
      }
  };`;

  }
```

But still I am getting above mentioned error that smartvideo tag is not defined

I also added no errors schema in `Video-page.component.ts`, but still issue persists

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,Component,  Renderer2, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({

  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]

})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-page',
  templateUrl: './video-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-page.component.css']
})
export class VideoPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _renderer2: Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are trying to use a tag named 'smartVideo', angular then expects that you have a component named smartVideo, but it can't find it and errors out.

In the component you defined there should be a `@NgModule` annotation, in the properties add `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` and that should solve it. (second line in the error message)

Comment: I also added it ..

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: []
})

Comment: But not working . Is the above code in comment is correct or not ?  @noahp78

Answer (score 0):

You can add `smartvideo` into the `class` to use Swarmify now

```
<smartvideo class="smartvideo" style="min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;" src="http://www.example.com/sample.mp4" width="600" height="600" controls></smartvideo>
```

FYR:
https://support.swarmify.com/hc/en-us/articles/360057623814-Using-a-standard-HTML-Video-tag-with-SmartVideo